# Warning in install.packages : installation of package 'xxx' had non-zero exit status on R

Tags: r, package

I just remove and install new R. My current R version is "R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)".

I try install several packages but everytime I did it, I got error like

[image]

My .libPaths() values are below:

```
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library" 
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Does anyone has idea how to deal with this issue?

Please note that this case occurred when I tried to install to any package

Comment: 2 things:
1. Did you have that package installed before?
2. It clearly says that your C compiler is not working. Go to your shell terminal and type `which gcc` to see if you have `gcc`.

Comment: I installed several times since it did not works at first time installation. Below is the output when I type which gcc on terminal :

/usr/bin/gcc

What should I do next?

Comment: It's not clear what unix operating system you are using: is it mac osx or linux? If you are using a mac, you will need to download and install [java for mac](http://supportdownload.apple.com/download.info.apple.com/Apple_Support_Area/Apple_Software_Updates/Mac_OS_X/downloads/031-29055.20150831-0f779fb2-4bf4-11e5-a8d8-/javaforosx.dmg) first before you can install `rjava` or `xlsx` in R.

Comment: It linux mint and it already solved after I installed C compiler. Thank for the solution.